# How to declare an object array length within another object

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that has 3 Objects; Hotel, Room and Bed. Object Bed will hold information about the bed. Object Room will hold information about the room including how many beds it contains. Object Hotel will contain information about how many Rooms it contains.

my code for the Hotel class looks like this

```
public class Hotel {

    private String name;
    private boolean HasVacency = false;
    public int numberOfRooms;
    Room[] rooms = new Room[numberOfRooms + 1];

    public Hotel() {


    }

    public void setRoom(int numberOfRooms) {
        this.numberOfRooms = numberOfRooms;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }





}
```

And the code for the test class where i create the hotel and declare the values looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HotelTest t = new HotelTest();
    t.getHotelInfo();



}

public void getHotelInfo() {
    Hotel test = new Hotel();
    int numberOfRooms;
    int numberOfBeds;
    String size;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("what is the name of the hotel");
    String name = input.next();
    test.setName(name);

    System.out.println("how many rooms does the hotel have");
    numberOfRooms = input.nextInt();
    test.setRoom(numberOfRooms);
    System.out.println(test.rooms.length);


    for( int i = 0; i< test.numberOfRooms + 1; i++) {

        System.out.println("how many beds does room " + (i + 1) + " have");
        numberOfBeds = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i);
        test.rooms[i].setNumberOfBeds(numberOfBeds);

    }

}
```

however i keep getting a null pointer when i try to set the value for the number of rooms in test. Sorry for the messy code

Answer (score 1):

A few things to look at here. Your code breaks encapsulation (you have public members of your hotel class being accessed by other classes); you could make use of constructors to make things a bit neater; look at creating the hotel from its components upward instead of a top-down approach. I've included some sample code based on yours.

```
public class Hotel {

    private final List<Room> rooms;

    private final String name;

    // constructor to initialize hotel with name and number of rooms
    public Hotel(String name, List<String> rooms) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public Room[] getRooms() {
        return this.rooms;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

}

public class Room {

    private final int beds;

    // constructor to initialize a room with the number of beds it needs
    public Room(int beds) {
        this.beds = beds;
    }

    public int getBeds() {
        return this.beds;
    }

}

public void getHotelInfo() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("what is the name of the hotel");
    String name = input.next();

    System.out.println("how many rooms does the hotel have");
    int numberOfRooms = input.nextInt();

    List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();        

    for( int i = 0; i< numberOfRooms; i++) {
        System.out.println("how many beds does room " + (i + 1) + " have");
        int numberOfBeds = input.nextInt();

        // create a room with the number of beds specified and add it to the list of rooms
        Room room = new Room(numberOfBeds);
        rooms.add(room);
    }

    Hotel hotel = new Hotel(name, rooms);

    // from here on, if you want the hotel's name or its rooms, you can use the appropriate getter methods in the Hotel and Room classes

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hotel {

    private String name;
    private boolean HasVacency = false;


    public Hotel(int numberOfRooms) {

        Room[] rooms = new Room[numberOfRooms + 1];

    }



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

I modified your Hotel class. In your old code array of room were being initialized before you are updating numberOfRooms. Create Hotel object like this   `Hotel test = new Hotel(numberOfRooms);`